# .Net Core Web API not deserializing JSON from angularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have this angular JS controller where I am serialising a view model to json which doesnt deserialise on the backend with a web api.

Here is my angular controller constructor..

```
constructor($scope, $http, $routeParams: IBookingParams) {

        this.http = $http;

        //get parameters from Recommendation page
        this.bookingView = <IBookingViewModel>{};
        this.bookingView.CampaignName = $routeParams.CampaignName;
        this.bookingView.CampaignSupplierId = $routeParams.CampaignSupplierId;
        this.bookingView.SupplierName = $routeParams.SupplierName;
        this.bookingView.MediaChannelNames = $routeParams.MediaChannelNames;
        this.bookingView.MediaChannelIds = $routeParams.MediaChannelIds;                    

        let livedate = this.GetJSDate($routeParams.LiveDate);
        let liveDateTime = this.GetDateTime(livedate);

        this.bookingView.LiveDate = liveDateTime;
        //populate the rest of our model 
        this.bookingView.Action = "from angular";

        var model = this.bookingView;
        let json = JSON.stringify(model);               

        this.http({
            url: "/api/asdabooking",
            method: "POST",
            data: json
        })
            .then((response: any) => {
                let test = "";
            })
            .catch((data: any) => {
                let test = "";
            });
    }
```

Here is my web api

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/asdabooking")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> BuildBookingModel([FromBody]BookingViewModel model)
    {
        try
        {
            //model is null??!!
            return Ok("");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            base.Logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);
            return BadRequest(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This is pretty bizarre, the bookingView view model on the front end matches the fields on the backend view model "BookingViewModel.  I have inspected the json and all looks ok.

This is my view model

```
public class BookingViewModel
{
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }
    public string CampaignSupplierId { get; set; }
    public string SupplierName { get; set; }
    public List<string> MediaIds { get; set; }
    public List<string> MediaChannelNames { get; set; }
    public List<MediaChannelViewModel> MediaChannels { get; set; }
    public string Action { get; set; }
    public DateTime LiveDate { get; set; }
    public List<int> MediaChannelIds { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }     
    public bool SuccessfulSave { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Track which tab is updating
    /// </summary>
    public string TabAction { get; set; }
    /// <summary>
    /// Price summary - list of media channels (tabs)
    /// </summary>
    public List<MediaSummaryViewModel> MediaSummaries { get; set; }

    public string UserMessage { get; set; }

}
```

This is my json

[image]

Comment: What headers are being passed in the request?

Comment: None, just the json in the data of the request

Comment: There has to be headers being passed along in the request. I suspect it's missing the Content-Type header, which should be set to "application/json". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Type

Try taking a look at the request in developer tools or in a tool such as Fiddler.

Comment: I didnt do that before but I added it 'Content-Type': "application/json" in the headers param of the http object but still the same problem.. I will try postman..

Comment: When I run into issues like this, typically I find it's easiest to just get the request working through some type of debugging tool like Postman, then tweak your code based on your findings.

Comment: Definitely! thats what i started doing.. should have used postman sooner! I think the view model on the front end needs to be camel case, so CampaignName should be campaignName

Comment: The json is using camel case, I am supplying the header form postman and still the same issue.. it must be a .net core web api thing...

Comment: If you inspect the ModelState when you enter the WebAPI controller method, does it indicate that there are errors? I believe it might tell you what's happening if you dig into it - perhaps in the ModelState.Errors collection. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.modelstate?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2

Answer (score 0):

Often when I run into this issue it is caused from the types within the JSON object not matching the types of your properties that you defined within your model.  I would ensure those types match.  It also might help folks interested in answering this question to post a snippet of your JSON object as well as your model class.

Comment: that's more of a comment than an answer but I have added both.

Comment: I would have commented but I did not have enough Stack Overflow Rep to do so.  It looks like your model does not match your JSON object.  First, the name of the JSON properties will need to match that of the API Model.  If you correct the naming of properties within your JSON object and you are still having an issue it might be worth looking at how you registered that action on the API side.  It looks like you are not supplying the entirety of the BookingViewModel in the body of the post request.  To get around this you can define some of the properties of the controller as optional.

Comment: The problem is the array of MediaChannelIds is coming in as an array of strings with quotes.. I did specify it to be an array of numbers in typescript though.. something went funny when it was assigned to the model. But for the record it doesnt matter if a field is missing completely or assigned null, it still deserializes.

Comment: Thanks anyway. Using postman and tinkering with the json is the best way to get to the bottom of these issues.

Comment: Ah that is interesting!  I did not know that the act of deserializing added missing properties to the object.  Glad you got to the bottom of it

Comment: Thanks! yea I was reading values for the json from $routeParams in angularJS which caused the issue and gave me strings for those media ids.

Answer (score 0):

mediaChannelIds should be

```
"mediaChannelIds":[ 
  4,
  5]
```

This is because I was getting an array from a query string using $routeParams by referring to the same parameter more than once which is a bad idea.. better to separate values with a character to get an array because you cant make it typesafe with $routeParams.. it will always give you strings.

In the JSON You can miss out fields or pass null no problem and it will still deserialise, but you can't mismatch types or the whole thing comes back as null.